# Rails deployment to AWS ECS container service through Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-5, capistrano3, amazon-ecs

I am investigating the possibilities to deploy my Rails application to ECS containers instead of Amazon EC2.

I currently have configured a Capistrano deployment on an Amazon elastic load balancer, I am wondering how much I need to do in order to achieve something similar for ECS.

I am using rails with nginx + passenger. I was thinking of using passenger-docker as a base image to deploy containers

I think I need to automatize the following steps

- Write a Dockerfile that is capable of building a new container image with the latest dependencies/configuration for my app (and the newest version of passenger-docker)
- Register the new image on my ECS image repository
- Update the existing ECS cluster with the new image (if possible one at a time, to avoid downtime)

Is it possible to use Capistrano for that ? How would I write a capistrano deployment file ?

Answer (score 0):

Capistrano isn't really a useful tool for Docker based deployments. Capistrano is useful for automating deployment of repository revisions to a shared server.

See this prior question: [How to integrate Capistrano with Docker for deployment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39457603/how-to-integrate-capistrano-with-docker-for-deployment)